# Optimize base64 encoding & decoding in C

Tags: c, optimization, encoding, base64

I am developing an application in **C** to send video log of running session. For that I am using client server architecture.

**Client**

- Captures the screen every second in a series of frames .
- Encodes the frame i.e. byte array by using base64
- And sent to targeted server in thread function by calling web services API (in C#).

**Server**

- Server receives the byte array decodes them to form an image (in C#).

**PROBLEM :-**

- When I connect from one machine with 2 or more live sessions, the CPU utilization goes to 100% and everything seems to freeze.
- I am not able take & capture more than 1 live session as base64 encoding is too heavy and time consuming to process.

Looking for some optimization technique for BMP files in base64 at client side before sending over to server.

Thank you in advance.

**EDIT :**

Code uses openssl functions for encoding at client side and it is mandatory as normal string with some special characters are discarded and blocked by gSOAP which provides connectivity with C# services at server side.

```
char *base64(const unsigned char *input, int length)
{
    BIO *bmem, *b64;
    BUF_MEM *bptr;

    b64 = BIO_new(BIO_f_base64());
    bmem = BIO_new(BIO_s_mem());
    b64 = BIO_push(b64, bmem);
    BIO_write(b64, input, length);
    BIO_flush(b64);
    BIO_get_mem_ptr(b64, &bptr);

    char *buff = (char *)malloc(bptr->length);
    memcpy(buff, bptr->data, bptr->length - 1);
    buff[bptr->length - 1] = 0;

    BIO_free_all(b64);

    return buff;
}
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/205762/discussion-on-question-by-vivek-optimize-base64-encoding-decoding-in-c).